# Why did it get so complicated to download & install QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation

Why did it get so complicated to download & install QGIS on Windows? A few months ago, it was easy to choose the right version, the download-files were small, the installation was quick. Now is is the opposite: it is complicated to choose the right version, the download-files are large and the installation takes quite a lot of time.

Are there any chances this will change in the future and things will get easier again?

[image]

Comment: It looks like they try to explain the alternatives on that page. And that proj_data https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ-data is a large resource nowadays.

Comment: You surely have proof to back up your claims? Or are you fine after you vented?

Comment: I get the venting part - we've all been there.  In fairness to the OP, the "Note for existing users" section still confuses me!

Comment: It is currently so complicated because the newer OSGeo versions need a fresh install if you are upgrading from an older version. Once this passes I imagine it will be simple again. Even simpler than before because there will no longer be a 32 bit version. I do think the order should be reversed with the stand alone installer at the top of the page.